# strops NOT contains specific multiple words in PHP

Tags: php, strpos

I would like to check if the user types a word that it doesn't in the list. 
For example, we require user to include "apple", "orange", "cake" 
if the user type "I eat an orange", nothing will happen. 
But if the user type "I eat a hamburger", something will happen. (hope you understand...) 
I know it can be done by using strpos, but it can only use one word. I also searched other examples on stackoverflow about using OR ||, but still, it doesn't work.

edited, here is the actual code:
I want to prevent user use other email services (only google, yahoo and outlook)
The first work, but the other two doesn't work...

```
<?php
if (strpos($email, 'gamil.com') == false) {
  $_SESSION["register_stat"] = "email";
}
?>

<?php
if (strpos($email, 'gamil.com') || strpos($email, 'outlook.com') || strpos($email, 'yahoo.com') == false) {
  $_SESSION["register_stat"] = "email";
}
?>

<?php
if (strpos($email, 'gamil.com') == false || strpos($email, 'outlook.com') == false|| strpos($email, 'yahoo.com') == false) {
  $_SESSION["register_stat"] = "email";
}
?>
```

Comment: Please show the code you've tried already.

Comment: show your code what you have tried so far? [Read how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Added the code.

Comment: `if (!preg_match('~@(?:gmail|outlook|yahoo)\.com$~i', $email)) $_SESSION["register_stat"] = "email";`

Comment: @Deadooshka it works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The other 2 don't work... What's your input? [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) will return 0 if the needle is found.

> Returns the position of where the needle exists relative to the
>   beginning of the haystack string (independent of offset). Also note
>   that string positions start at 0, and not 1.

You use conditions without `== false` and with `== false`, is that on purpose?
You might want to change `== false` to `=== false` since `== false` equals 0 as well.

More information about these operators can be found here:
[Comparison Operators ¶](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

> $a == $b  Equal   TRUE if $a is equal to $b after type juggling.
>
> $a === $b Identical   TRUE if $a is equal to $b, and they are of the same type.

When your `strpos` returns 0, this is what will happen:

`(int) 0 == false` will return true. They aren't the same type, but have equal value.

`(int) 0 === false` will return false. They aren't the same type, even though the value is the same.

Comment: The $email is an form text input. But I'm sorry I don't understand what does this "You use conditions without == false and with == false, is that on purpose?" mean?

Comment: You use `strpos($var, 'string')` and `strpos($var, 'string) == false`, is that intentional? Are you aware of that? Shouldn't all comparisons be either `== false` or just `strpos`?

And again, what input do you use for testing? Does the test fail with every input or just specific values?

You really need to give us more information if you want some help.

Comment: Sorry I don't give much information to you. I tried abc@gmail.com, the first one work, but the other two doesn't work. I tried abc@test.com, all of them doesn't work. I tried abc@yahoo.com, still, all of them doesn't work.

Comment: The second and the third method, I reference two example on stackoverflow, to try which one really work for me, but none of it works.

Comment: A person on top helped me solved the question, but anyway, thank you for helping me.